# eorror comes when try to run unit test case using jasmine to test angular 2 component

Tags: angular, components, karma-jasmine

When I run npm test command to run my jasmine test case testing Angular component functionality I get the following error:

```
**789:ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined.**
```

Comment: Formatting, grammar, removed redundancy

Comment: Please provide the relevant sections of your code.

Comment: can not share the code can you please let me know why its error come.

Comment: It could be any one of a thousand reasons.  At the very least tell us what versions of the tools you are using.

Comment: you need not share the exact code. A code similar to what you have should be able to give indication. Otherwise your question is not very helpful.